# Best way to use a set of integers as SQL key?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I find myself needing to store some data for sets of integers, and I wonder how to do that best.

The simple way is to simply sort them and make a string to use as a primary key. This 205 char string is a typical example:

`"1 8 9 10 13 14 15 19 25 35 41 73 78 106 107 112 121 138 166 167 169 182 185 187 190 194 197 248 253 483 497 752 767 1605 1609 1614 1652 1748 1874 1925 1934 2533 2635 2636 2643 2685 2809 2867 2876 3303 3361"`

I'm sure that will work, but it seems clumsy and ineffective. Are there any tricks of the trade people use? How much does the string length matter here?

I'm in Postgres if that matters.

Comment: You can use an array: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/arrays.html

Comment: Is there any reason to store the set as the key, rather than having some ID that you reference and storing the set itself as part of the data?

Comment: The reason is that I'll query using that set. This is a cache. Someone creates a new set, and if we already have data for it, it avoids 20 seconds of computing.

Comment: The Postgres array type is interesting!

Being bound to Postgres bothers me only slightly. I'll have to see how indexing on an array column performs compared to a big string.

Comment: What is your typical use case 1) must contain *some* of the keys 2) must contain *all* the keys 3) must contain *exactly* this set of keys?

Comment: It must be that exact (unordered) set. So 3).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your use-case appears to be:  I have an application that generates a set of integers.  If it has seen these integers before, then it can look up the answer rather than spending time computing.

For this purpose, using the generated string of ordered integers as a primary key would appear to be a reasonable solution (assuming that ordering is not important for your application).  Personally, I would be inclined to hash the string, for a fast lookup, but that really isn't important for a binary tree search.

Actually, having said that, Postgres supports [hash indexes](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/indexes-types.html):

```
CREATE INDEX name ON table USING HASH (column);
```

Because you only want equality comparisons, this is the best index for you to use.

As a_horse_with_no_name points out, though, hash indexes are basically useless, and the binary tree should be just fine for the index.

Comment: Well, _almost_ supports hash indexes... The lack of WAL logging is a pretty big downside. Looks like this is [on track for Postgres 10](https://commitfest.postgresql.org/13/740/), though.

Comment: A BTree index is just as fast as a Hash index for equality lookup.

Comment: If *space* might be worrysome, an actual hash can be computed, and save in  a B-Tree index: `CREATE INDEX idx ON table USING ((md5(column)))` would do the job. I'm using MD5 as a hash function. It is probably an *expensive* one and better alternatives can be found. I don't think it applies to the kind of keys shown...

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name . . . Do you have a reference on that?  I would expect the hash to be faster, otherwise why bother supporting a hash index at all?

Comment: @GordonLinoff: there are several discussions on this topic on the mailing list, e.g. [here](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/flat/CAFcOn293Rzi7cZYWBT8tjxCtNX5pYdbknANXgf9mWfBizK8Frg%40mail.gmail.com#CAFcOn293Rzi7cZYWBT8tjxCtNX5pYdbknANXgf9mWfBizK8Frg@mail.gmail.com) "*The big picture though is that we're not going to remove hash indexes,
even if they're nearly useless in themselves*" But I think there is some work in progress for Postgres 10 to remove the limitations

Comment: Thanks!

I'll start by using a simple string. I found a way to make the string 60% smaller, and I expect that will be good enough. If not, I have some leads on things to try.